# By Default Location of Image in Android

Tags: android, android-camera

When we take a snap through emulator where does this image goes..And how can i retrieve it by giving its location address

Answer (score 0):

examine the emulator with the adb-shell. Note that by default no sd-card is mounted on the emulator. for loading the image you'll find plenty of examples, just google for 'loading image android'.

Comment: no basically when camera i take picture from cam......Then Is this pic store in some media file *...Then how can we get that pic.